# Dynamically create Swing GUI from generic XML

Tags: java, xml, swing, user-interface

I would like to dynamically create a Java Swing GUI from generic XML, and have the GUI output XML.

Can anyone suggest a framework please? I did try JAXFront, it would potentially fulfill my requirements, however I found it buggy, inflexible, and poorly documented.

This question differs from others on stackoverflow in that we start from generic XML, and the output is XML.

Comment: What do you mean by "generic XML"?

Comment: No custom elements that are required by the framework. I want to be able to take any XML, and turn it into a GUI.

Comment: What is the GUI supposed to do? I can create an empty JFrame after reading and ignoring an XML file, thus fulfilling the requirements you stated so far.

Comment: @Jens - but that would be silly. The gui will allow a user to input data on couriers, name, location, range etc.

Answer (score 3):

I think I know what you're asking for...

How about using [SwiXML](http://www.swixml.org/) plus Java's inbuilt XML APIs.

SwiXML would solve the Swing form generation, and Java's built-in XML APIs could bridge the gap between this and your 'generic xml format'. The [Java DOM API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/package-summary.html) would provide everything you need for transforming and generating XML.

Overview:

1. You could transform your 'generic xml' document into SwiXML's
   XML format, using one of Java's XML APIs such as DOM or SAX (or even
   an XSLT transformation).
2. Then you could invoke SwiXML on the resulting SwiXML markup.
3. Finally, you'd get your Submit button's ActionListener to generate the 'generic
   output XML' using e.g. Java's DOM API.

Hope this helps!

Comment: It does indeed, I would prefer to avoid step 1, but i understand this may not be possible.

Comment: I would like to do the same, did you make any progress on this?